# How can I put background image in React - TailwindCSS dynamically

Tags: reactjs, image, tailwind-css

```
<div className={`flex items-center bg-cover h-[73vh] content-end lg:h-[50vh] lg:content-center lg:items-center lg:justify-center bg-[url('${slideImage.url}')]`}>
                        {slideImage.content}
                    </div>
```

and URL is this

```
url: '../assets/images/shopHeroSliderImage1.jpg',
```

When I change it to a link it is working but when I change it to a value it is not. How can I put this image into background dynamically? and image path is correct i need to go parent folder first.

I need to get images locally from my computer and show them but can't do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/background-image), you can't have dynamic values in Tailwind.

You can put the path name like this:

```
<div className="bg-[url('../img.png')]"></div>
```

But if the path name is long you can make a custom class:

```
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      backgroundImage: {
        'hero-pattern': "url('/img/hero-pattern.svg')",
        'footer-texture': "url('/img/footer-texture.png')",
      }
    }
  }
}
```